# jquery ajax response empty

Tags: jquery

I've run into a difficult issue with ajax.  I've got 2 files.  1 file calls the other, using the .ajax api.  So far I have no issues.

The problem I'm running into is due to how I return a response to the ajax, from the 2nd file.
Usually I use the php "return" function. Which then lets me decide what to do with that text.
However, I really really want to use the die() function on the 2nd file.

File 1:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/myfile.php",
    data:"formId=processorder",
    error:function(){alert("error occurred");},
    success:function(response){alert(response);}
});
```

---

File 2: (myfile.php)

```
<?php

  // this does not work
  die("Message I want to return");


  // this does work, but don't want to use it
  return "Message I want to return";

?>
```

---

I want to use die() because it stops the process completely.
Am I doing something wrong?

I suppose doing both would possibly be the work-around. But that seems a little overkill. So, I thought I'd ask first.

Comment: Did you try `echo "Message I want to return"; die();`? And are you sure you get to that point of execution? A `die('whatever')` means you should catch in the ajax request the "whatever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anything you 'echo' will be sent back in the response. So you could...

```
echo "Message I want to return";
die();
```

Comment: That's what I thought.
I've used die() plenty of times before.  And it always seemed to perform the same as 'echo', at least in this aspect.  But I'm obviously not correct. :)

Comment: it is strange that die doesn't return the value as according to the php manual, die(status) is equivalent to exit(status) which "If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting." Maybe try exit instead of die and see if it returns a response?